# Run time for first and last index as a pivot in Quicksort?

Tags: quicksort

What is the running time of quicksort if we always use the first index as the pivot? What if we always use the last index as the pivot? Is the running time $O(n)$?

Comment: Argument and/or experiment.

Comment: The answer depends on the input. The worst-case running time will be $\Theta(n^2)$, the best case running time will be $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: Your question is answered [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: the worst-case does not depend on the input, as it pertains to the inputs that yield the worst cost.

Comment: The running time, though, does depend on the input.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: your comment was about the worst and best case running times. They don't depend on the input.

Comment: The answer to the question "what is the running time of quicksort" depends on the input.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: we agree on that. Anyway, we can give $O$ and $\Omega$ bounds that do not depend on the input. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case running time is not influenced by the strategy to select the pivot and is $O(n^2)$.

The average case is also not influenced if the distribution of the input is uniform, and is $O(n\log n)$.

The average case can be biased when the distribution is not uniform. For instance it will tend to $O(n^2)$ if there is a strong bias in favor of initially sorted arrays.